# Can we turn off the new jump animation?

Tags: eve-online

In the latest EVE Online expansion - Odyssey - the system jump "loading bar" has been replaced with a nice animation which hides the loading bar while you're travelling between systems. However, as a side effect of hiding the loading bar, if you're unable to make the jump for whatever reason (I just got stuck with a traffic control message stating my jump request would be authorised in 160 seconds), you're essentially left on the jump animation.

Once the counter has finished counting down, you can get out of the animation by selecting "jump" again but before this point you're stuck in the jump animation with no system overview and no obvious way to get out of the animation.

Can we turn off the new jump animation?

As a bonus question; where is your ship during the animation? As stated, all of the objects from the system overview menu disappear so it's acting like you're in limbo, but the message itself and the action (or lack of action) is very similar to when Jita is locked down (due to too many people in the system) - is your ship actually sat next the gate?

Comment: Have not played eve for a long time but if there is not a fix for this it seems game breaking annoying. Get a good insurance till you get a answer ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to turn off the jump animation, the old jump system is just not there anymore. [From a CCP BunnyVirus on the official forums](https://forums.eveonline.com/default.aspx?g=posts&m=3140338#post3140338):

> > Giovannui wrote:
> >
> > The new jump animation introduces too much lag when
> >     multi-boxing. is there a way to turn it off? If not, please give us
> >     the ability to use the old system again.
>
> there is no old system anymore

I'm not sure how the new jump system interacts with traffic control or any of the other reasons preventing a jump. But I would assume that any significant difference to the old behaviour would be a bug and you should just report it to CCP.

If the gate can't be activated for any reason, you used to be an easy target on the gate while unable to jump. I would assume that this behaviour is still the same.

Comment: I have submitted a petition asking!

Comment: Currently you sit idling next to the gate you activated until the animation finishes - it has been reported as a potential issue